# Problems with specifying bibliographic punctuation stylings in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm looking to specify my own custom bibliographic punctuation stylings in a report I'm writing on the LaTeX platform on Overleaf.

However, I'm receiving a few issues. I'll outline all the key lines in my `main.tex` file:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\TOCadd{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

I'm also using '`\citep{...}`' as outlined in the Natbib section here: [LaTeX/Bibliography Management: Natbib](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management). However, a quick screenshot of my inline references:

[image]

I'd like my references to be:

(Massey et al., 1995; Humphreys et al., 2014)

I'm also seeing 'and' and not '&':

[image]

But I'd like this to be:

Robitaille & Whitney 2010

If anyone is able to help me on these two issues I would be very appreciative. I just can't see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Moving `\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}` to _before_ `\begin{document}` will clinch things for the brackets. 

Instead of `\bibpunct`, you can also use the newer command `\setcitestyle` to change to round brackets: 

`\setcitestyle{round}`

Comment: To change `and` to `&` though, you'll have to upload a modified copy of `plainnat.bst`. Or switch to a bibliography style that uses `&` e.g. `agsm`, then add `\setcitestyle{semicolon}` to get `;` separating the citations.

Comment: Could you add your solution as a full answer for me. I'd like to implement your suggestions but I'm unsure as to the exacting details. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving `\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}` to before `\begin{document}` will clinch things for the brackets. Instead of `\bibpunct`, you can also use the newer command `\setcitestyle` to change to round brackets: `\setcitestyle{round}`

To change `and` to `&` though, you'll have to upload a modified copy of `plainnat.bst`. Or switch to a bibliography style that uses `&` e.g. `agsm`, then add `\setcitestyle{semicolon}` to get `;` separating the citations.

In summary: it seem to me the following would give what you want:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
% agsm already use round brackets, so "round" isn't necessary
\setcitestyle{semicolon,aysep={}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{\&}}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because I'm still seeing 'and'. Would it change things if I mentioned I am using overleaf?

Comment: my bad — apparently `\setcitestyle` undoes the change to `&`! Adding a line `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{\&}}` changes in back. (Re-defining `\harvardand` doesn't work with `plainnat`, because it doesn't use it.) I've now updated my answer. This isn't specific to Overleaf, it's how natbib and the styles work. :-)